# Mysql group by subsequent

Tags: mysql, datetime, group-by

I need a particular group by query.
I have a list of events with (title, start, end) fields
I would like to get a event title, number, first and last event rows grouping by title and **subsequent** start-end datetime with a little slack (example 15 minutes).

For example:

```
create table events(
  id int auto_increment,
  title varchar(50),
  start datetime,
  end datetime
);

insert into events values
('Title1','2013-07-15 12.00','2013-07-15 13.00'),
('Title2','2013-07-15 12.00','2013-07-15 13.00'),
('Title1','2013-07-15 13.15','2013-07-15 14.15'),
('Title1','2013-07-15 14.30','2013-07-15 15.30'),
('Title1','2013-07-15 19.00','2013-07-15 21.00');
```

The result should be:

```
'Title1', 3, '2013-07-15 12.00','2013-07-15 15.30'
'Title2', 1, '2013-07-15 12.00','2013-07-15 12.00'
'Title1', 1, '2013-07-15 19.00','2013-07-15 19.00' (not susequent [+/- 15min] with first group)
```

Is it possibile?
Thank you.

Comment: How does 15.00 comes from in your first resultset?

Comment: It should be `'Title1', 3, '2013-07-15 12.00','2013-07-15 15.30'
'Title2', 1, '2013-07-15 12.00','2013-07-15 13.00'
'Title1', 1, '2013-07-15 19.00','2013-07-15 21.00'`

Comment: You're right, I'm sorry, I miss the first result row but others are right I need just first and last "start" field not end...

Comment: Where's your PRIMARY KEY?

Comment: Consider it as Auto_increment... i add this in the DDT

Answer (score 0):

No, SQL isn't that flexible unfortunately.

You need either stored procedure or doing a full select and resolving the problem on the application level.

Answer (score 0):

This is a complicated query.

The idea is to define where a sequence starts -- that is, each record that is more than 15 minutes after a preceding record.  Then, for each record, count up the number of such records before it.  This provides a "group identifier" for each sequence.

The calculations, in MySQL, involve correlated subqueries (or non-equijoins with aggregation).  The innermost calculates `StartGroup`, which are the records where a sequence starts.  The next level sums these up for the group identifier:

```
select grp, title, count(*), min(start), max(end)
from (select e.*,
             (select sum(StartGroup)
              from (select e.*,
                           (select (case when e1.end < e.start - interval 15 minute
                                         then 1 end)
                            from events e1
                            where e1.title = e.title and
                                  e1.end < e.start 
                            order by e1.end desc
                            limit 1
                           ) as StartGroup
                    from events e
                   ) e2
              where e2.title = e.title and
                    e2.start <= e.start
             ) as grp
      from events e
     ) e
group by grp, title
```